# Is it possible to use a mounted file in a docker file

Tags: docker

Is it possible to perform commands in a dockerfile on a file which you are going to mount.
I want to build an image and every user who creates a container from that image is able to mount their own volume with the `-v` option.
Now my problem is the fact that I have to change the permission of that file inside my container. So I was wondering if it was possible to perform a chmod on that file (in my dockerfile) while that file wasn't mounted yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to do it when the file is already mounted.

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to avoid that people need to perform manual commands inside my container. They mount a file in the container. The container will use that file but it's only possible to use the file if it has the right permissions).

Comment: The only possibility, as I can see, is that you change file permissions by adding a CMD or ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile.